# What is difference between @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) and @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) 
public void foo1() {
    `/**Some Code**/`
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void foo2() {
    `/**Some Code**/`
}
```

Comment: Propagation.REQUIRED ->current  transaction will be used  or create a new one if none exists.

Comment: rollbackFor = Exception.class -> means if 'Exception.class' or any other which extends this class will be thrown during transaction, whole transaction will be rollbacked. Without any changes made

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` and `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` are roughly the same. As `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED` is [the default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#propagation--). So with that in mind they are equivalent to `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` and `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)`.

The only difference is that without the `rollbackFor = Exception.class` it will rollback only for `RuntimeException`s and `Error` s not for other exceptions that occur. (This is the same for JEE when using EJB and the behavior has been translated to Spring as well).

This is also explained in the [javadoc of `@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html).

Comment: Read again... It states -> **without** the `rollbackFor`....

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, by default `propagation` is always present if you write it or not. If you write `rollbackFor` then the transaction will be rollback if an exception happens.

Here is a link for more help:[@Transactional](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring)

Answer (score 0):

What `propagation` and `rollbackFor` focus on are different, `propagation` cares **the way how transaction needs or creates**, `rollbackFor` cares **whether the existed transaction roll back or not** while the specified exception occurs.

Please refer to the [@Propagation docs](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) to get more details.

As the default propagation level is `Propagation.REQUIRED`, so the main difference between two annotations in your question is whether rollbacking for Exception(checked Exception) or not.

Comment: I believe M. Deinum's answer is the appropriate one for this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898227/what-is-difference-between-transactionalrollbackfor-exception-class-and-tr/54900186#54900186)

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran What he sayed is right, but more things can be done by combined