# Spring Data JPA Rollback If Save Method Throw Exception

Tags: java, jpa

**Problem solved : Go to last entry**

I am trying to test my method's rollback function if any exception has thrown from save method of crudrepository. I have a main loop which scans my file and for each row then insert a record into table. I realized that when any exception occured, loop breaks but rollback operation doesn't work. What am I missing? Thanks in advance

## Main Code

```
@Component
public class ExcelReader {

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void openExcel() throws IOException {
        int insertedRowCount = 0;
        int updatedRowCount = 0;
        int exceptionRowCount = 0;

        //some codes

        while (true) {
                //some logic
                City2CityEntity city2CityEntity = new City2CityEntity();


                city2CityRepository.save(city2CityEntity);
                if(insertedRowCount == 500){
                   throw new RuntimeException();
                }
                insertedRowCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(insertedRowCount + " number of rows inserted");
        System.out.println(updatedRowCount + " number of rows skipped");
        System.out.println(exceptionRowCount + " couldn't inserted");
    }
}
```

## Repository

```
@Repository
public interface City2CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City2CityEntity, Long> {
    Iterable<City2CityEntity> findAll();

    City2CityEntity findByCompanyAndOrgAndDst(String company, String org, String dst);
}
```

## Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx_berkin_city2city", schema = "CRANE_AT", catalog = "")
public class City2CityEntity {
   //getter setters and fields
}
```

After 501. record inserted, I threw an exception.

Comment: Don't annotate a PostConstruct method with Transactional. Instead, call *another* bean's transactional method after your application context has started. Assuming Spring Boot, from here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : I solved problem. I removed **@PostConstruct** annotation on top of openExcel function. Then used ExcelReader bean with using applicationContext.getBean() method from main class. Now everything works perfectly. I didn't have to use any parameter for @Transactional annotation anymore.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({FileProperties.class, TargetProperties.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        ExcelReader excelReader = applicationContext.getBean(ExcelReader.class);
        try {
            excelReader.openExcel();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

This is the answer above. I found here: 
[What is difference between @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) and @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898227/what-is-difference-between-transactionalrollbackfor-exception-class-and-tr)

Comment: This is incorrect. Runtime exceptions cause rollback automatically.

Answer (score -2):

try to use next:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) // your exception
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Runtime exceptions cause rollback automatically.

Comment: yeah, that's why i added a comment near, but forgot to say that should be a checked exception

Comment: The exception that the user throws is not a checked exception. It's a runtime exception. And runtime exceptions cause rollback autmatically. So adding `rollbackFor = Exception.class` is useless. It would be useful if the OP wanted all checked exceptions to cause a rollback, and if the method was called from another bean.

Comment: Oh, okay!
Thanks a lot:)