# Rollback a transaction when a query throws an exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

folks,

The method below is part of a transaction using JPA. I'm trying to discover how to add a functionality in this method so when the query within the method throws an exception, all the transaction rolls back.

What could I do in this case? Below is the code:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteDadosSExecReenvCancelada(Long nuSeqConsecao){
        try{

            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append(" DELETE FROM sigpc_fnde.s_execucao_financ_gru_reenv where NU_SEQ_EXEC_FINANC_REENV in (SELECT NU_SEQ_EXECUCAO_FINANCEIRA FROM sigpc_fnde.s_exec_financ_reenv where NU_SEQ_CONCESSAO = ?)");

            getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query.toString()).setParameter(1, nuSeqConsecao).executeUpdate() ;

            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.append(" DELETE FROM  sigpc_fnde.s_exec_financ_reenv where NU_SEQ_CONCESSAO = ?");
            getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql.toString()).setParameter(1, nuSeqConsecao).executeUpdate() ;

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.getCause();
        }

    }
```

I would like to know if simply the Annotation @Transactional(rollbackFor=true) guarantees this condition to happen.

Comment: I think its `rollbackFor = Exception.class` (not `= true`). Rekated: [What is difference between @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) and @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898227/what-is-difference-between-transactionalrollbackfor-exception-class-and-tr)

Answer (score 0):

[`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) will detect any unchecked exception thrown in your method and your transaction will be marked as rollback only. I think `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` is not necessary in your case since all possible exceptions that could be thrown are `RuntimeException`.

Also, your `EntityManager` needs to be injected by Spring. If it's not the case, let Spring inject the `EntityManager`.

An example on how you could let Spring inject the bean:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyService {

...

    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

...

}
```